Do CAT 8 ethernet doublers exist?
I bought a CAT 8 ethernet cable (40Gps) but I need to split the signal, does doublers of this type exist?
I need a 40Gps doubler, so one female entrance that ends with two other females exits at the other side, but all the products I find online are supporting max 1000MB.
Also I think that probably the network switch that supports 40Gps are super expensive, since I saw some products online.
Does such a doubler exists?

Are you talking about distributing a single Ethernet link to two devices? That's a network switch.

Why do you think you would be able to do anything you are talking about on cat8?  You can't split signals on gigabit connections (and AFAIK you can't do it on any ethernet network).    Sounds like you need a 40Gbps switch to do what you are asking - but how are you going to push 40 gbps anyway - and what does KVM have to do with anything?

As signals get faster this kind of splitting can have a really bad effect. You could possibly do it back in the day because signals were slower and electronics could compensate for the noise and problems it would cause. Nowadays this would probably take your 40Gbps line and make it run at (maybe) an unreliable 1Gbps or even worse.

For a network to support a speed of XGbit/s, it starts with the hardware, which then requires cabling to match the hardware. A CAT8 cable won't transmit >1Gbit/s, with a 1Gbit/s network card, >2.5Gbit/s with a 2.5Gbit/s network card, etc. (even then, it would likely be cheaper to go with fiber optic cards and cables).

If you do split the cable then you absolutely would cut potential throughput dramatically. Get yourself a 2.5GB/sec copper switch. 40GB/sec will be extremely expensive and the hardware on the other end will require fiber to guarantee those speeds.

What is the speed of the Ethernet interfaces of the devices you want to connect?
